# Why can't I specify any local domain for web development?

Tags: apache, hosts

I just tried doing this on my localhost machine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.testsite.local
 DocumentRoot /home/testsite/
</VirtualHost>
```

While doing this in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.2.5 www.testsite.local
```

To my amazement, Google Chrome doesn't let me load `www.testsite.local` in the browser. It does the websearch instead.

Can I force Chrome to load this string as a domain? If not, what is a simple and correct way to specify a local domain? I don't want to use the real domain, because I don't want to keep commenting/uncommenting the `/etc/hosts` file whenever I want to switch between live/dev versions.

Comment: Can't you name it "localhost"?

Comment: In any case, if you type `http://www.testsite.local` to Chrome it won't redirect to web search.

Comment: Juhana: how exactly? static.testsite.localhost, www.testsite.localhost, etc?

Comment: No, just `ServerName localhost`

Comment: So how do I differentiate among site's subdomains then?

Comment: You should probably add to the question that you need subdomains. But the http:// prefix should work.